# Windows 10: Problem on registering filebeat service using provided powershell script

Tags: windows-10, filebeat

I want to register and use File Beats as a windows service.

so, I ran the service registration script provided on the official website, but an error occurred.

error : PSSecurityException (UnauthorizedAccess)

My system os version is Windows 10 and I want to install version 7.10.0 of Filebeat

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must set execution policy to obtain permissions

You can try this:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Now, you can use the provided powershell script.

```
PS> .\install-service-filebeat.ps1
```

You have to start the service after execute the script.

```
PS> Start-Service filebeat
```

If you want to remove the execution policy, use this command:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy Undefined
```

I checked that this command able to used with Filebeat 7.10.0 and Windows 10 Environment.

Thank you. Have a nice day :)